# полиморфные переменные

Tags: java

разбирали такой код в университете:

**Класс Car:**

```
public class Car {
    public void drive() {
        System.out.println("Машина едет");
    }
}
```

**Класс Bmw:**

```
public class Bmw extends Car {
    @Override
    public void drive() {
        System.out.println("Бмв едет");
    }
}
```

**Класс Mercedes:**

```
public class Mercedes extends Car {
    @Override
    public void drive() {
        System.out.println("Мерседес едет");
    }
}
```

**Класс Audi:**

```
public class Audi extends Car {
    @Override
    public void drive() {
        System.out.println("Ауди едет");
    }
}
```

**Класс Main:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car bmw = new Bmw();
        bmw.drive();
        Car mercedes = new Mercedes();
        mercedes.drive();
        Car audi = new Audi();
        audi.drive();
    }
}
```

Это я понимаю: Набор методов, которые можно вызвать у переменной, определяется типом переменной. А какой именно метод какая реализация вызовется, определяется типом/классом объекта, ссылку на который хранит переменная.

А кроме этого есть ли преимущества делать тип ссылочной переменной класс родитель? И вообще почему больше всего примеров где тип ссылочной переменной родитель?

Comment: вы не понимаете , что такое полиморфизм и зачем он нужен... боюсь, что это не тема форума, ведь объяснить это в двух словах довольно сложно, к тому же на эту тему есть огромное количество учебного материала

Comment: @Дмитрий Я понимаю, я ниже написал что так и так будет работать, смысл в нем тогда?

Comment: понимание синтаксиса языка и осознание факта, что любой объект можно записать в переменную типа его суперкласса, не является пониманием полиморфизма и уж тем более умением его применять

Answer (score 0):

Очень часто используется при реализации полиморфизма. Чаще всего `Car` это вообще абстрактный класс или интерфейс. И тогда при передачи объекта в методы другого объекта, например в метод `toWash` класса `СarWash` используется ссылка по типу `Car` так как автомойке не обязательно (даже скорее не нужно) знать какой марки автомобиль необходимо помыть, действия все равно будут происходить одинаковые (намочить, запенить, смыть и тд.). Тем самым происходит избавление от дублирования кода (иначе вы бы создавали множество методов `toWash` с разными по типу принимаемыми параметрами Audi, BMW и тд, но с одинаковым телом).

Comment: Так даже если будет Bmw bmw = new Bmw(); а в методе toWash будем передавать Car car, то мы без проблем передадим экземляр класса bmw с типом Bmw и не будет ругаться компилятор

Comment: Используя `Bmw` вы лишний раз привязывайтесь к конкретной реализацией интерфейса `Car`. Если это было сделано без надобности (использовать например какие-то методы и поля класса `Bmw`) то завтра если будет необходимость заменить `Bmw` на новый класс `Ford` вы можете столкнуть с большими проблемами (и большим переписыванием кода). На простом примере это может быть не заметно, но в огромных проектах на тысячи модулей, привязки к конкретным реализациям сделает код менее гибким к изменениям.